# How to find the fitting version of pgadmin III?

Tags: postgresql, pgadmin

If you have different versions of PostgreSQL database servers you need a pgadmin III version with the respective pg_dump and pg_restore included.

I am running pgadmin III on a windows machine.

For example for PostgreSQL server 8.4.x you need pgadmin III with pg_dump 8.4.x, for PostgreSQL server 8.3.x you need pgadmin III with pg_dump 8.3.x and so on.

What I cannot figure out is how do you know which version of pgadmin III contains which version of pg_dump and pg_restore? I could not find the info on http://www.pgadmin.org/download/windows.php

I could just install some versions and try out, but maybe there is a better way.

---

```
pgadmin III V 1.8.4 comes with pg_dump 8.3.15
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way is to download the corresponding PostgreSQL server installer for windows and install it. At the same time pgadmin III will be installed - alongside with the corresponding pg_dump and pg_restore from that PostgreSQL server version.

Comment: Unfortunately, not found docs about compatibility matrix. 
your method is very practical.  
win zip here (bundled docs can tell pgadmin version)  https://www.enterprisedb.com/download-postgresql-binaries

Answer (score 3):

The most up-to-date version is always available with the most-up-to date version of postgres. So the coming 1.14 of pgAdmin support 9.1 with it's features, 1.12 -> 9.0, 1.10 -> >8.4. I noticed that pgAdmin will disable (or disallow you to use) certain features that do not support your installed pg version.

*Sidenote*: I made bad experiences with using the build-in backup/restore tools from pgAdmin (on Linux), no idea why this wasn't working but one machine just wasn't able to import a backup made by another one with same version, specs,... Had this issue many times, so I always prefer the command line export/import. The latter has never failed and offers more options for exporting and importing.

Comment: OK, but this does not answer the question. It would be great to have a list of the corresponding versions. What you write only always works for the latest version. My question refers explicitly to different versions (on different machines of course) - which includes also older versions.